# Can I use history.js on IE9

Tags: history.js

Thought of using the plugin https://github.com/browserstate/history.js to maintain browser state in IE9 . Is it supported. I get the following error when I try to use it
0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'pushState'

If it is not supported please suggest something that will work.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, history.js is supported in IE9 according the gituhb repository you linked to.

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js#browsers-tested-and-working-in

The browsers supported (currently) are:

- Firefox 4+
- Chrome 8+
- Opera 11.5+
- Safari 5.0+
- Safari iOS 4.3+
- IE 6, 7, 8, **9**, (10)
- Firefox 3
- Opera 10, 11.0
- Safari 4
- Safari iOS 4.2, 4.1, 4.0, 3.2

Comment: Would you know which script file works with IE9. I am currently using native.history.js

Comment: The downloaded demo files does not work in IE9. I get the same error.

Comment: Any help on how to save browserstate